# Unable to save canvas data

Tags: android, canvas

> 07-24 12:36:23.742: W/System.err(10386): java.io.IOException:
>   Permission denied 07-24 12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method) 07-24 12:36:23.750:
>   W/System.err(10386):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1257)
>   07-24 12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):  at
>   com.android.SignaturePage.FileWrite(SignaturePage.java:414)
>   07-24 12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):  at
>   com.android.SignaturePage$2.onClick(SignaturePage.java:132)
>   07-24 12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 07-24 12:36:23.750:
>   W/System.err(10386):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 07-24 12:36:23.750:
>   W/System.err(10386):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 07-24
>   12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 07-24
>   12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 07-24 12:36:23.750:
>   W/System.err(10386):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 07-24
>   12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-24
>   12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 07-24 12:36:23.750:
>   W/System.err(10386):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   07-24 12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 07-24
>   12:36:23.750: W/System.err(10386):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**code Snippet where I am getting error**

```
public  void FileWrite(File aPath,String aBody)
{
    try 
    {
        //System.out.println("@@@@ Inside Try FileWrite @@@@");
        Log.e("BEFORE FILE","BEFORE FILE");
        aPath.createNewFile();
        Log.e("AFTER FILE","BEFORE AFTER");
        PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(aPath);
        out1.write(aBody);  
        //System.out.println (aBody.trim());
        out1.flush();
        out1.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        //System.out.println("@@@@ Inside Catch FileWrite @@@@"); 
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Manifest file has following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Please help me in solving the issues.
`aPath.createNewFile();` 
is line where the error is taking place

Comment: try
     {
      FileWrite(SignSave,"confirmation");           

File SignSave=new File("data/data/com.myapp.android.creditcardreader/SignConfirmation");
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
 File SignSave=new File("data/data/com.myapp.android.creditcardreader/SignConfirmation");
```

1. typically access to this path requires the root permission
2. you forget the first `/` in data:  `File("/data/...);`

Edit:

you shoul store the file inside  the `sdcard`. You can access the root of the `sdcard` in this way:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
File aPath = new File (root, "confirmation");
aPath.createNewFile();
```

Comment: 07-24 12:54:58.523: V/log_tag(10844): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.epaisa.android.creditcardreader/signature.png (Permission denied)
07-24 12:54:58.531: W/System.err(10844): java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Comment: do you know what does "root permission" means?

Comment: have no idea about it. Shall I change the directory ?

Comment: The superuser (root) is a special user account used for system administration.

Comment: made changes as you suggested but still finding an issue

07-24 13:13:50.320: W/System.err(11226): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard (Is a directory)

Comment: the issue is now on    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(aPath);

Comment: I have managed to remove that issue. Now the issue is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard (Is a directory)

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` to your manifest and it should work.

Comment: already haev these permissions<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: How do you build the path? you try to do getDir("signature.png", MODE_WORLD_READABLE)